# Executing local bash script remotely, interactively, with arguments

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, shell

From all of my testing it seems like it is not possible to execute a local script remotely while allowing an interactive shell and passing arguments.

Interactive *(arguments try to run as a seperate command either inside or outside the double quotes)*

```
ssh -t server "$(<${scriptname})"
```

Arguments *(Not interactive ofc)*

```
cat $scriptname | ssh -t server bash -s - "${args[@]}"
```

I have really tried this every which way. Is it possible to both start an interactive shell and execute the script while also sending arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to have answered my own question by considering changing the values of of the $@ arguments on the remote to the ones locally passed and it seems to work in my tests.

Here is my final solution on just switching out $1 and $2

**Local Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "I wanna read you $1 and $2"
read yn

if [ "$yn" == "y" ]; then
    echo "I read you"
else
    echo "I could not read you"
fi
```

**Command**

```
ssh -t $server "set -- "${@:1:2}"; $(<${script})"
```

**Result** *(when sending test1 and test2 as arguments)*

```
I wanna read you test1 and test2

y

I read you!
```

Hopefully this helps any future visitors

Answer (score 0):

As an academic question, I'm sure if you are a wizard at shell escaping and parameter expansion, you could do it.  I wouldn't recommend it though.

As a practical matter, I do:

> scp script.sh me@server; ssh me@server "./script.sh"

pretty often.

If you want to do real work remotely over ssh, you should look into [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/)

Comment: Hi there. I was definitely familiar with Ansible. I believe to have answered my own question however after logically giving it some more thought. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Oh come on!  What was the answer?

Comment: The answer is the ... answer. Right above the one you commented on